# In androidstudio default toolchain `aarch64-linux-android-gcc` does not exist

Tags: android, android-ndk

[According to this page I don't need to be using the standalone toolchain anymore.](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain) I updated to NDK 20 so this should work for me I thought.

However, as soon as I started to try and recompile my C++ dependencies (ffmpeg at first), I found out `aarch64-linux-android-gcc` is needed. But this file does not exist *anywhere* under the `$NDK` dir (it does exist in the standalone toolchain directory).

So I'm confused, because the impression I got from this

> Warning: If using r19 or newer, follow the Other Build Systems document for instructions on using the NDK toolchains with arbitrary build systems. As of r19, the NDK's default toolchains are standalone toolchains, which renders this process unnecessary.

was that I could use the existing toolchain. And my question is: Is that information wrong, should I continue using the standalone toolchain, or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standalone toolchains won't help you if your build is using GCC. GCC is no longer supported by the NDK. You need to either (preferably) convert the build to use Clang or (understanding that this means you're going to be struggling with bugs that have since been fixed) downgrade your NDK to a version that supported GCC (r17).

Comment: I forgot how I fixed my problem - I think by fixing the LDFLAGS I was using or something like that - but this seems like a decent answer so I'm accepting it.